# EC2 Ubuntu - nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-config

I'm getting this error after running `sudo nginx` command

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Here is my security settings on AWS EC2:
[image]

In my Django project, I've created an config file for nginx: (nginx.conf)
(I'm also using `uwsgi` as the second web server that is working fine)

```
# the upstream components nginx needs to connect to
upstream dcohort {
        server unix:///tmp/dcohort.sock;
}

server {
        listen               80;
        listen               [::]:80;
        server_name          *.amazonaws.com;

        access_log off;
        error_log  /home/ubuntu/dcohort/logs/nginx_error.log;

        location / {
                include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass  dcohort;
        }
}
```

then imported the configuration to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
http {
        include /home/ubuntu/dcohort/config/nginx.conf;
        # ...
}
```

Comment: ugh, seeing the same issue. also nginx+Django. I had the setup working fine, but after stopping the old ec2 machine and creating the new one , nginx won't restart, and letsencrypt certbot fails the certificate dance for this reason. most likely the config went bad...

Comment: Getting the same error here, guys any of you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

did you check the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled? it contains links to sites-availabe, usually the error caused by your configs conflicts, like using port 80 more than once in different configs, you should remove or update one of the port